# Can a polytope with vertex-transitive edge graph or face lattice be made vertex-transitive?

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes

Let $P\subset\Bbb R^d$ be a *convex*, full-dimensional polytope (convex hull of finitely many points, affine hull is the whole space), $G_P$ its edge graph and $\mathcal F_P$ its face lattice. Any of these is called *vertex-transitive* if the respective symmetry group (isometries, graph isomorphisms or lattice isomorphisms) acts tansitively on its vertices.

Are there any known results on the following questions?

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. If $G_P$ is vertex-transitive, is then $\mathcal F_P$ also vertex-transitive?
> 2. If $G_P$ is vertex-transitive, is there a vertex-transitive polytope $Q$ with $G_P$ as edge graph, maybe in the same dimension $d$, maybe even combinatorially equivalent to $P$ (i.e. with isomorphic face lattice)?
> 3. If $\mathcal F_P$ is vertex-transitive, is there a vertex-transitive polytope $Q$ with $\mathcal F_P$ as its face-lattice?

The answer is always *No* if we not already know that $G_P$ or $\mathcal F_P$ belong to an actual polytope, or if we replace vertex-transitivity by a weaker form of symmetry (e.g. central symmetry).
On the other hand, for $d\le 3$ all answers are *Yes*.

Comment: 2-neighborly polytopes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighborly_polytope) have vertex-transitive edge graphs, but $\mathcal{F}_P$ is rarely vertex transitive.

Comment: @RichardStanley Are there any easily accessible examples for this? As far as I know the cyclic polytopes can be realized vertex-transitively.

Comment: When $d$ is odd and the number of vertices is at least $d+3$, then no realization of the cyclic polytope is vertex transitive. See Theorem 8.3 of http://www.math.uni-magdeburg.de/~kaibel/ALT/Downloads/cyclaut.pdf. Shemer (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02761235) showed in 1982 that there are super-exponentially many neighborly polytopes (improved by Padrol in https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2810). I suspect that  most of them are not vertex transitive.